# Regarding missing and duplicated binaries

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I use Subversion as source code repository. Now we have decided to check-in the binary dependencies in SVN. Earlier those dependencies were not checked in SVN, so what structure should I follow to store binaries in SVN so that there are no duplicated or lost binaries. (some optimized way of storing binaries in SVN).

Comment: Why are they missing or duplicated? How do you know they're missing or duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your decision.

Binary files in repositories take up a lot of room. Text files can be easily compressed, but binary files cannot be. Text files can be easily diffed, but not binaries.

Let's say you have a binary file that's around 256 Mb. That's not all that big, but every time you check in a change, you are adding another 256Mb into your Subversion repository. Check in one version of this file once per week, and you've added 12Gb of files into your repository. That's one file after one year of commits.

And, binary files have no real history to them. All you can see is who checked in the binary. You can't see what change was made. You can't even see what files were compiled into the binary. Nor, can you *merge* binary files. If you made changes in a branch, you can't merge the binary in that branch into your trunk.

So, versioning your binary files will quickly overwhelm your Subversion repository (It isn't unusual for 95% of a repository to be nothing but storage of binary file history). But, you get nothing in return. Binary files have no real history attached to them. They can't be merged for their differences, and their value is short lived.

It is much better to store your binaries into a *release repository*. You didn't say what you're building, but C#/.NET can use NuGet as a release repository. If you are building Java applications, you can use Ant with Ivy, Gradle, or Maven. If you use C/C++, you can use wget or curl to pull out the prebuilt binaries. There's no reason to store binaries in Subversion.

Comment: If the only option is to use Subversion for storing binaries, then what structure should be followed to store binaries?

Comment: If you must store binaries, create a separate repo for them. At least your not polluting your source repo. This way, when the repo gets too big, you can delete it and start over.

Comment: What are these binaries you're storing? Are they third party code? Stuff you built? Libraries used by other programs? Code for release and testing? What language are you writing your code in?Give me some info, and I'll be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: They are third party binaries and libraries used by other programs. I write code in java.

Comment: Java? You should be using a Maven repository like Nexus or Artifactory. You can use Maven to do builds, or take a look at Ant with Ivy. Ivy provides you the ability to use Maven repositories, but allows you to use your current Ant build files.